# Scrapy with dynamic content forms

Tags: python, scrapy

I'd like to use scrapy to rip some websites that require authentication.
I read this would be possible by using formdata but the problem I'm currently facing is that the input name is randomly generated every time the login page is refreshed.

Here is the html code:

```
<input type="text" name="MemberNameb326ccc51594e4" id="MemberNameb326ccc51594e4" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" tabindex="1">
```

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the input name since it's dynamic, you can get the reference of that input by getting it's surrounding element, for example

```
<div id="static-id"><input type="text" name="MemberNameb326ccc51594e4" id="MemberNameb326ccc51594e4" size="15" maxlength="20" value="" tabindex="1"></div>
```

once you have that surrounding container, you can get the name of that input

Comment: So I assume it could be possible to use response.xpath inside formdata. I can't seem to find any examples on the syntax.

Comment: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login you need to scrape the form so that you will know the current input name, then build your formdata dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be better to use python [Beautifulsoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) module, and once the html soup is done, you may use [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module to find corresponding id, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#get the url page content
html = request.get("http://mysite.url/toscrap").content
#soup the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
#find all inputs containing "MemberName" in id field
my_inputs = soup.findAll("input",{"id":re.compile("MemberName")})
```

which will fit your needs by giving you any input fields where id containing "*MemberName*"

Regards